# How do I read a data in .txt format using keras framework?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, parameters, neural-network, row

I need to train a fully-connected neural network classifier using a dataset in .txt format as training data. How can I read the data set using keras framework?

I have to use less than 40 parameters,and only the first 100 rows of the dataset

Answer (score 0):

To read in .txt data to Keras you can `tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer`, see the documentation here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer

You still have to open the file and read in the data with the Python function `open`. You can then use the the tokenizer to read the data into a numerical representation.

Here's an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

data = open('dataset.txt').read()

# Tip: You can specify characters which is to be ignored here as well.
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=40)

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data)

# Here we use a binary representation, I recommend looking into the representation that fits your training data needs.
data = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(data, mode='binary')

train_data = data[:100]
```